# Use values of string array A as keys in object O when A and O are both properties of an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-constraints

I want to create a type that is an object, with properties `values`, and `valuesMap`.  `values` should be an array of strings, and `valuesMap` should be an object whose keys are entries in `values`, and whose values are either a string or a boolean.  I am struggling to define this type constraint in typescript.  Here's what I've tried:

```
type FilterOptionBase<K extends string> = {
  name: string;
  values: K[];
  multiselect: boolean;
  isBoolean?: boolean;
  valuesMap?: {
    [key in K]: string | boolean;
  };
};

type FilterOption = FilterOptionBase<string>

const myBadFilter: FilterOption = {
    name: 'Status',
    values: ["Online", "Offline"],
    multiselect: false,
    valuesMap: {
        Online: true,
        NotSure: false // <------ should error but doesnt
    }
}
```

### [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgeTMOB7AdgIQEMBnCAHgGkoIAPZXAE2KmOBTlwHMA+KAXigBvAFBQouQgFsIALhZsOnANyioAN0IIArhGJyKAbQC6KsZK1I4pBBADGwOQCNs2G4VymoV-C7e4A-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)

I feel like this should be relatively simple but the solution is escaping me.  If this has been asked before, please direct me to the right place!

#### Also:

If `isBoolean` is defined as `true`, can we also contrain the values of `valueMap` to be a boolean, rather than a `boolean | string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your example isn't working is because this:

```
type FilterOption = FilterOptionBase<string>
```

...is passing `string` into `FilterOptionBase`, essentially doing this:

```
type FilterOptionBase = {
  name: string;
  values: string[];
  multiselect: boolean;
  isBoolean?: boolean;
  valuesMap?: {
    [key in string]: string | boolean;
  };
};
```

So to type it correctly, you'd need to pass in the list of strings you'd expect when using the type, like this:

```
const myBadFilter: FilterOptionBase<"Online" | "Offline"> = {
  name: 'Status',
  values: ["Online", "Offline"],
  multiselect: false,
  valuesMap: {
      Online: true,
      NotSure: false // <------ errors now!
  }
}
```

However, I think what you're *actually* trying to do is use the `FilterOptionBase` type as a template of sorts for all kinds of different objects, and the unfortunate part is that there's no way to do it that way. You can't have a type that is both reading from itself *and* constraining itself.

But you *can* access the values on an object *that's passed into a function*, so here's a workaround that I've used in the past to great effect:

```
const filterFactory = <K extends string>(v: FilterOptionBase<K>) => v

const myBadFilter = filterFactory({
  name: 'Status',
  values: ['Online', 'Offline'],
  multiselect: false,
  valuesMap: {
    Online: true, 
    NotSure: false, // <------ it's an error!
  }
})
```

**"Also" Answer**

Yes, it's possible to change it based on `isBoolean` being `true`. You'll just need to do a union:

```
type foo = {
  isBoolean: true
  value: boolean
} | {
  isBoolean: false
  value: string
}
```

Though it does get a little trickier because of the workaround you have to do with the factory function. Here it is:

```
type FilterOptionBase<
  K extends string,
  B extends boolean | undefined,
> = B extends true
  ? {
      name: string
      values: K[]
      multiselect: boolean
      isBoolean: B
      valuesMap?: {
        [key in K]: boolean
      }
    }
  : {
      name: string
      values: K[]
      multiselect: boolean
      isBoolean?: B
      valuesMap?: {
        [key in K]: string
      }
    }

const filterFactory = <K extends string, B extends boolean | undefined>(
  v: FilterOptionBase<K, B>,
) => v

const myBadFilter = filterFactory({
  name: "Status",
  values: ["Online", "Offline"],
  multiselect: false,
  isBoolean: true,
  valuesMap: {
    Online: true,
    Offline: "foo", // <------ also an error!
  },
})

const myOtherBadFilter = filterFactory({
  name: "Status",
  values: ["Online", "Offline"],
  multiselect: false,
  isBoolean: false,
  valuesMap: {
    Online: true, // <------ also an error!
    Offline: "foo",
  },
})
```