# typescript strong type event emitter based on name of event

Tags: typescript, generics, inferred-type

I have an module that export a number of pure functions

example:

```
export function concat(a:string, b:string):string{ }
export function sum(a:number, b:number):number{ }
```

I created a type using Parameters utility and name of the function

```
import * as m from './helpers';

type Helpers = 
 { type:"sum", payload:Parameters<typeof m.sum> } | 
 { type:"concat", payload:Parameters<typeof m.concat> };
```

using this type; I was able to strong type a utility function that takes in 2 arguments (name & payload) and call the correct function

```
function caller(action : Helpers){
  return m[action.type].call(this, action.payload);
}
```

it kinda works as expected, but i have to manually add type to Helpers type everytime i add a new function to the module

question 1: is there a way I can automatically infer type for caller function?

2nd i have an eventemitter that i use to emit events `emitter.emit(action.type, action.payload)` .. i want to type the `emitter.on("sum", (...props)=>{})` function so that once user define first argument(T) in `.on` the callback gets typechecking that match type payload of type with type=T.

thanks

Comment: This is a tough one.  I got close with [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/wR9xvW), but it seems to have just gotten trickier from there.  You may try to create a generic `Helper` type, but that sort of creates the same problem I was having [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69399117/use-values-of-string-array-a-as-keys-in-object-o-when-a-and-o-are-both-propertie).